# How to match Markdown Setext headers in in exuberant ctags

Tags: regular-expression, newlines, markdown, ctags

I am working on a language definition for pandoc markdown in ctags. However, I have problems matching Setext headers in the regex which are defined by multiple `=` or `-` in a new line under the header text. Setext headers look like this:

```
My Firts Level Setext Header
============================

My Second Level Setext Header
-----------------------------

### My Third Level Setext Header
```

The manpages for exuberant ctags mention that it uses extended POSIX regular expressions with `\n` for newline supported.

Thus, `/^(.*)$\n={3,}` should match a markdown Setext header at `\1`

The corresponding language definition in my `.ctags` looks like this:

```
--langdef=pandoc
--langmap=pandoc:.pandoc
--regex-pandoc=/^(.*)$\n={3,}/\1/h,Heading_L1/
--regex-pandoc=/^(.*)\n-{3,}/\1/i,Heading_L2/
--regex-pandoc=/^###[ \t]+(.*)/\1/k,Heading_L3/
```

However, tags are only created for level 3 headers which do not need new line matches. For Level 1 and 2 headers there are no tags/matches in the `tags` output file.

For instance:

```
Introduction    dissertation.pandoc /^### Introduction$/;"  k
```

Why is this and how can I match Setext headers in exuberant ctags?

Comment: I (personally) don't have enough to go on for this Q; it's been a couple days with no other comments or answers, so if you still need help, I'd recommend adding in any other context (sample input & output) so that more people have a chance of reproducing the problem and hopefully finding a solution.

Comment: OK, a suggestion to generalise the question. Explain (by means of an example) what a "Setext header" is. This looks to be a question predominantly asking about REs but since I don't know what one of these headers is, I can't help you match it.

Comment: I think this feature might not be supported yet. See https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags/issues/219

Comment: @Erotemic what about this merged pull request? https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags/pull/1224

Comment: sounds like the option I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solve the same problem. I am persuade the [Exuberant Ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) does not support multiline regular expressions. 
But, there is successor project [Universal Ctags](https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags), which support that.

Universal Ctags configuration can be divided to multiple files. For more information look to `ctags/doc/optlib.rst` on the project website.

**I created following configuration file:** `~/.ctags.d/optlib/markdown.ctags`

`--langdef=markdown
--langmap=markdown:.md
--regex-markdown=/^(.+)[[:cntrl:]]{1,3}^(===+)/\1/h,Heading_L1/{_multiline=1}
--regex-markdown=/^(.+)[[:cntrl:]]{1,3}^(---+)/\1/i,Heading_L2/{_multiline=1}
--regex-markdown=/^###[ \t]+(.*)/\1/k,Heading_L3/
--excmd=number`

**The `tags` file can be generated by the command:**

`ctags --options=markdown -R test.md`

The new is `{_multiline=N}` flag. The number `N` is number of group in the pattern. Position of the text in the file represented by this group is saved in the `tags` file. In the future we want to jump to the name of the header not underline. So we have one group `(.+)` and we link to it with `{_multiline=1}`.

I had problem to check new line in the regex. Simple to use `\n` or `\r` does not work. For check new line can be used named group `[[:space:]]` or `[[:cntrl:]]`. I think `[[:cntrl:]]` is better because it does not include common spaces.

The next problem is different line endings for DOS and Unix files. If the  file use Unix line endings the quantification in pattern `{1,3}` can be omitted. Obviously use quantification is more general but it sometimes can cause problems with the Unix line endings file.

Is not perfect, but I did not found better solution.

Comment: added the below line to a `Markdown.ctags` file within my `$HOME/.ctags.d` directory,

```
--regex-markdown=/^###[ \t]+(.*)/\1/k,Heading_L3/
```

and that ☝️ line causes a failure to build a proper tags file. ‍♂️

running universal-ctags installed from git source cira february 2020